# Netfonds.no: Continuing to understand how to get high frequency data

Tags: equities, market-data, high-frequency, historical-data, tick-data

I first found out about [netfonds](http://www.netfonds.no/) about a year ago but I hadn't ever really gotten around to actually pulling data from there. I spent a little time today figuring out a way to pull data and here is what I found.

Obviously there is no free, flawless high frequency database available and this is the best thing I have ever seen.

Ideally I would have someone who speaks Norwegian validate this but google translate will have to be the stand in for lack of a better option.

#### Exchange codes:

`NASDAQ: O`
`NYSE: N`
`AMEX: A`
`BATS: BTSE` *this is Bats Europe so only euro stocks availible*

Using these codes, you can access all of the currently traded symbols using this link:

#### Exchange listings:

http://www.netfonds.no/quotes/kurs.php?exchange=A&sectors=

- This link will show you all of the available symbols that are currently being traded and are available for download.

Using those symbols you can pull 1S bid/ask and trade data.

#### Link to grab trades:

`http://hopey.netfonds.no/posdump.php?date=[YYYMMDD]&paper=[SymbolFromExchange].[ExchangeCode]&csv_format=csv`

**Sample: SPY**

time,price,quantity,source,buyer,seller,initiator
             20160706T153000,207.83,600,Auto trade,,,
20160706T153000,207.84,100,Auto trade,,,
20160706T153000,207.835,100,Auto trade,,,
20160706T153000,207.82,100,Auto trade,,,

#### Link to grab bid/ask:

`http://hopey.netfonds.no/posdump.php?date=[YYYMMDD]&paper=[SymbolFromExchange].[ExchangeCode]&csv_format=csv`

**Sample: SPY**

time,bid,bid_depth,bid_depth_total,offer,offer_depth,offer_depth_total
20160706T011205,208.52,6400,6400,208.57,2600,2600
20160706T011257,208.54,6400,6400,208.6,3200,3200
20160706T011307,208.54,6400,6400,208.59,200,200
20160706T011316,208.57,3000,3000,208.59,200,200

#### Notes:

- These links will not work unless you enter the proper information. They will provide data for the past 11 business days.
- US Market open is 0930, and open marked on Netfonds is 1530. Subtraction to get time would be even easier than having to mess with tz conversion in pandas or something like that.
- Only the first four columns are available from trade dump.
- Data doesn't appear to be adjusted for splits, mergers or dividends.
- The trade dump doesn't seem like it is every trade, I assume it is just the trades accepted by the exchange that did't have to be adjusted or messed with.

#### Questions

- It appears that there is no pull for bid/ask or trades for symbols on NASDAQ, I was unable to get any of them to download. Is there something else that needs to be included to get that data?
- Can you pull futures contracts or options from here, would be interested to figure out how to get those.

-What are all of the exchange codes available. Is there a way to pull a list of them or get more than the ones I have listed above?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the link is dead and the resources are no longer available online.